# Calling a function from a different react file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm close to getting this to work. Hoping someone can help me with this.

I have 2 React files. One being the `Container` and the other being the `Nav` component.

Inside my container component which is called `_template.js`, I'm importing a modal npm package. I created a `showModal` function inside this container file that I'm trying to access inside the `Nav` component.

This is what I have so far and receive this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal' of undefined`

_template.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


import { prefixLink } from 'gatsby-helpers';
import { config } from 'config';

import Headroom from 'react-headroom';

import Nav from './nav.js';

import '../css/main.scss';

import Modal from 'boron/DropModal';

const modalStyle = {
  minHeight: '500px',
  backgroundColor: '#303841'
};

const backdropStyle = {
  backgroundColor: '#F6C90E'
};

const contentStyle = {
  backgroundColor: '#303841',
  padding: '3rem'
};





export default class RootTemplate extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    location: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    children: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

  }

  showModal () {
    this.refs.modal.show();
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Headroom>
          <Nav showModal={this.showModal}/>
        </Headroom>
        <Modal ref="modal" modalStyle={modalStyle} contentStyle={contentStyle} backdropStyle={backdropStyle}>
          <form>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email"/>
            <label>Message:</label>
            <input type="text-area"/>
            <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit" />
          </form>
        </Modal>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And my Nav.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { prefixLink } from 'gatsby-helpers';



import { Nav, NavGroup, NavItem, NavToggle, Icon } from 're-bulma';



export default class nav extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav>
          <NavGroup align="left">
            <NavItem>
              <Link to={prefixLink('/')}>
              <h2>Dillon Raphael</h2>
              </Link>
            </NavItem>
          </NavGroup>

          <NavToggle />

          <NavGroup align="right" isMenu>
            <NavItem>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <a href="#" onClick={::this.props.showModal}>Let's Work!</a>
            </NavItem>
          </NavGroup>
        </Nav>



      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice the `<a href="#" onClick={::this.props.showModal}>Let's Work!</a>` this is where I'm trying to call the showModal function that I pass down from the `_template.js` file.

Comment: The `ref` doesn't exist, but why pass a `ref` to the `Modal` anyway? `Modal` takes a `prop` of `show`, so why not just use that instead of coming up with another solution?

Comment: @lux it says to use ref in the docs. https://github.com/yuanyan/boron. Are you saying to just do this.modal.show() instead?

Comment: Sorry, thought this was a `react-bootstrap` modal, which is fairly common. Haven't seen this one from `boron`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your constructor, in _template.js file this code:

```
this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
```

The constructor then should look like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: This worked! I thought to bind it inside the Nav file. Thanks!